Domain of convergence of complex series $z\not=1,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}3^{n}}\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^{n}$
I need to find the domain of convergence of the following series:
$z\not=1,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}3^{n}}\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^{n}$
Clearly the radius of convergence is $R=3$ since:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{\left|\frac{(n+1)^2 3^{n+1}}{n^2 3^n}\right|} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{n^2}{3(n+1)^2}\right| = \frac13$$
Now trying to solve $\left|\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right|<3$ for $z=x+yi$ I get:
$$\begin{align*}
\left|x+1+yi\right| & < 3\cdot\left|x-1+yi\right| \\
\implies \sqrt{\left(x+1\right)^{2}+y^{2}} &< 3\cdot\sqrt{\left(x-1\right)^{2}+y^{2}}\\
\implies x^{2}+2x+1+y^{2} &< 9x^{2}-18x+9+9y^{2} \\
\implies 0 & <8x^{2}-20x+8+8y^{2}\\
\implies 0&<\left(x-2\right)\cdot\left(x-0.5\right)+8y^{2}
\end{align*}$$
I got stuck here, according to desmos the solutions are in red: 
No clue how to procced or understand how can I get to that...
Thanks!

You almost made it. When you factor the quadratic in your last line you should render $8x^2-200x+8=8(x-2)(x-0.5$. So properly,$0\le(x-2)(x-0.5)+y^2$, where equality is accepted because of tge $1/n^2$ factor. The excluded region should be circular.

The power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n^2}$ converges if and only if $|z|\leqslant1$. Therefore, your series converges if and only is $\left|\frac{z+1}{3(z-1)}\right|\leqslant1$. But, if $x,y\in\Bbb R$ are such that $z=x+yi$, we have\begin{align}\left|\frac{z+1}{3(z-1)}\right|\leqslant1&\iff\left|\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right|\leqslant3\\&\iff|z+1|\leqslant3|z-1|\\&\iff|z+1|^2\leqslant9|z-1|^2\\&\iff(x+1)^2+y^2\leqslant9((x-1)^2+y^2)\\&\iff8x^2+8y^2-20x+8\geqslant0\\&\iff8\left(x-\frac54\right)^2+8y^2\geqslant\frac92\\&\iff\left|z-\frac54\right|\geqslant\frac34.\end{align}There is an error in your computations: it is not true that$$8x^2-20x+8+8y^2=(x-2)\left(x-\frac12\right)+8y^2.$$Rather, we have$$8x^2-20x+8+8y^2=\color{red}8(x-2)\left(x-\frac12\right)+8y^2.$$

oh I see now my mistake I also forgot about completing the square, I thank you for that!

I'm glad I could help.
